# Week view in Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Is there any option in bootstrap datetimepicker to just show it week wise like the image below
[image]

Comment: I have added my comment please give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does have .. I have mentioned url below please have look they have shared an example for it

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        calendarWeeks: true,
        //your other config options if you have 
    });
```

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#calendarweeks

Comment: That shows week numbers in the monthly view, not one week at a time like OP asked for.

Comment: Mate, Thanks for the help but I just want to show the calendar by only week view and not the whole month when the calendar opens.